# Regular Expression - extract digits

Tags: php, regex, string, filter

I have strings of text that may have the following formats:

Was £39.95 Now Only £29.00
OR
Was 0.95p Now 10p

What is the easiest way to extract two numbers from each string, so I can subtract them later.

Comment: How are you planning to differentiate  £29 and 10p? One is 2900p, the other 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This monstrosity will capture two numbers separated by text. It will also capture the units.

```
$match = preg_match("/((?:£)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:p)?)[a-z\s]*((?:£)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:p)?)/i", "Was £39.95 Now Only 99p");

print_r($matches);
```

This will yield:

```
Array (
    [0] => Was £39.95 Now Only 99p
    [1] => £39.95
    [2] => 39.95
    [3] => 99p
    [4] => 99
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression like the following:

```
/\d+(\.\d+)?/
```

Be careful because this won't read the units, so you could easily end up with an error if there is something like the following:

```
Was £2 Now Only 99p
```

You may also want to watch out for commas in your text string. Note that there are also internationalization issues here that you should be aware of. Many countries use `,` as a decimal separator and `.` as the thousands separator. You might be able to guess the locale from the currency (e.g. £ suggests that the decimal separator is `.`).

If you can be more precise about what sort of values your program must accept then you will probably get better answers.